# Posicionamento de componentes usando GridBagLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, panel

Estou fazendo um painel e quero  ter o seguinte layout:

A largura do painel ocupa toda a largura do frame, e quero ter 4 botões no canto direito desse painel.

Criei um painel como *container*, e dentro desse painel criei um outro painel com os 4 botões.
A ideia é que esse painel com os botões fique no canto direito do "painel container".

Eu consegui criar o painel com os botões com o layout que eu quero, porém não consigo coloca-lo no canto direito do meu *container*.

Segue meu código:

```
/**
 * @return {@link JPanel} com botões de ação.
 */
private JPanel createActionButtonPanel() {
    JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
    GridBagLayout grid = new GridBagLayout();

    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;  
    cons.insets = new Insets(1,1,1,1);  
    cons.gridy = 0;

    buttonPanel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    buttonPanel.setLayout(grid);

    cons.gridx = 0;
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Pesquisar"), cons);
    cons.gridx = 1;
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Novo"), cons);
    cons.gridx = 2;
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Editar"), cons);
    cons.gridx = 3;
    buttonPanel.add(new JButton("Excluir"),cons);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(backgroundColor);
    cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    cons.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
    cons.gridwidth = 1;

    panel.setLayout(grid);
    panel.add(buttonPanel,cons);
    return panel;
}
```

Fazendo desta maneira o painel com os botões ficam centralizados.

Estou fuçando para aprender a usar o `GridBagLayout`, então posso estar cometendo algum erro primário.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rodando seu código obtive isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Eu consegui criar o painel com os botões com o layout que eu quero, porém não consigo coloca-lo no canto direito do meu container.

Uma solução simples é jogar seu GridBagLayout dentro de um BorderLayout, escolhendo a posição EAST, também conhecida como LINE_END.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basicamente seu código estava assim:

```
contentPane = createActionButtonPanel();
setContentPane(contentPane);
```

onde o Panel criado pelo seu método era o filho do JFrame. Para fazer o BorderLayout ser o filho do JFrame e pai do GridBagLyout faça assim:

```
contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
setContentPane(contentPane);
contentPane.add(createActionButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Você obterá isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Estou fuçando para aprender a usar o GridBagLayout, então se eu estiver cometendo algo erro primário me avisem.

Basicamente o que você tem que fazer é saber a hora usar o melhor layout para cada ocasião, e em muitas ocasiões precisará usar uma composição de layouts.

Aconselho começar a estudar por aqui: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: Excelente resposta. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou ler esse artigo que vc indicou. Muito obrigado.