# Espaçamento com GridBagLayout

Tags: java

Estou montando um layout para testes com o GribBagLayout, porém estou com dificuldades com o posicionamento dos elementos. O frame possui dois *panel*. Quero que os itens do panel à esquerda (Label 1, texto 1...) fique com um pequeno espaçamento da esquerda e que o Label 1 possua também um pequeno espaçamento da parte superior, pois ele está "grudado". Minha principal dúvida é quanto aos *weight*, pois imagino que seja com ele que arrumo isto porém não consegui. Abaixo a foto e o código:

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.Dimension;
  import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
  import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
  import java.awt.GridLayout;
  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JButton;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;
  import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Teste{

private JButton btnCalc;
private JLabel origemText;
private JLabel destinoText;
private JPanel panel1, panel2;
private JLabel labelPanel2;
private JTextField texto1;
private JTextField texto2;

public Teste() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setTitle("teste");
    frame.setSize(1000, 500);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());


    origemText = new JLabel("Label 1");
    texto1 = new JTextField("Texto 1"); 
    destinoText = new JLabel("Label 2");
    texto2 = new JTextField("Texto 2");
    btnCalc = new JButton("Botão 1");

    GridBagConstraints cons = new GridBagConstraints();
    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(180, 200));

    cons.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 0;
    cons.weighty = 0.1;
    panel1.add(origemText, cons);

    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 1;
    cons.weighty = 0.2;
    cons.weightx = 0.1;
    panel1.add(texto1, cons);

    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 2;
    cons.weighty = 0.1;

    panel1.add(destinoText, cons);

    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 3;
    cons.weighty = 0.6;
    panel1.add(texto2, cons);

    cons.gridx = 0;
    cons.gridy = 4;
    cons.weighty = 9.0;

    panel1.add(btnCalc, cons);

    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    panel2.setSize(200, 300);

    labelPanel2 = new JLabel("Panel 2");

    panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 1));

    panel2.add(labelPanel2);

    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, panel2);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.WEST, panel1);


    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Teste();
}
}
```

[image]

EDIT

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você está procurando é o `Insets`:

```
cons.insets = new Insets(20, 20, 0, 0);
```

Exemplo de imagem com `Insets` zerado:
[image: Imagem sem Insets]

A mesma imagem, só que agora utilizando `Insets`:
[image: Imagem com Insets 15]

O `weight`, ao contrário do que você pensou, serve para tratar do tamanho dos elementos, quando a janela é *redimensionada*. A imagem da esquerda, a seguir, tem o `weight` de `0.5` para cada imagem. A da direita, está com `0.4` a primeira, e `0.6` a segunda, fazendo com que, ao serem redimensionadas, uma seja mais *cortada* do que a outra:

[image: Imagem com weights equilibrados][image: Imagem com diferentes weights]

Segue o código utilizado, caso queira testá-lo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

class TesteInsets extends JPanel {

    JLabel soLogo, soLogo2;
    BufferedImage img, img2;

    public TesteInsets() {

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        try {

        URL url = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/xIUCtPo.png");
        URL url2 = new URL("http://i.imgur.com/kmNQziR.png");

        img = ImageIO.read(url);
        img2 = ImageIO.read(url2);

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        soLogo = new JLabel();
        soLogo2 = new JLabel();
        soLogo.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img).
          getImage().getScaledInstance(175, 175, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));
        soLogo2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(img2).
          getImage().getScaledInstance(175, 175, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH)));

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

         c.weightx = 0.6;
         c.gridx = 0;
         c.gridy = 0;
         c.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 0);
         add(soLogo, c);

         c.weightx = 0.4;
         c.gridx = 1;
         c.gridy = 0;
         c.insets = new Insets(15, 15, 15, 15);
         add(soLogo2, c);

    }

    public static void criarInterface() {

    JFrame janela = new JFrame("Teste Insets");
    janela.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JComponent painelConteudo = new TesteInsets();

    painelConteudo.setOpaque(true);
    janela.setContentPane(painelConteudo);
    janela.setResizable(true);
    janela.pack();
    janela.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] Args) {

        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                criarInterface();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Visite o [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html#gridbagExample) para mais exemplos.

Comment: Funcionou amigo. Já tinha lida essa função do weight, mas fui usando e vi que ele estava meio que organizando o espaçamento, mas realmente é isso que você falou. Meio frame está com o setResizable(false), está certo o uso do weight nesse meu código? Ou nem precisaria?

Comment: @Ablon Se está com `setResizable(false)`, não vejo porquê utilizar o `weight`. Além disso, sugiro que você não defina o tamanho usando `frame.setSize()` - o ideal é que você deixe os elementos escolherem seus tamanhos, e utilize o `frame.pack()` no final.

Comment: Pois é, mas se eu retirar o weight, embora eu consiga determinar distância entre os elementos com o insets, eles ficam organizados no centro desse JPanel. Atualizei com o print

Comment: @Ablon O `weight` faz o que você quer, mas ele faz pelo motivo errado. É importante você imaginar como o seu *layout* ficará no final. A idéia de usar os *layout managers* é normalmente deixar que os elementos se "auto-posicionem" dentro deles. Se esse campo terá apenas esses cinco elementos e eles precisam ficar no topo, eu sugiro que você utilize outro *layout*, como o `BorderLayout` e coloque eles no `North`. Mas se você for eventualmente preencher o campo inteiro, é necessário adicionar novos elementos para que eles ocupem suas posições definitivas.

Comment: @Ablon Lembre-se que você pode colocar `JPanel` dentro de `JPanel`, com diferentes *layouts*! Um `GridBagLayout` dentro de um `BorderLayout` pode ser o que você procura (acho melhor do que "remendar" com o `weight`).

Comment: @Ablon acredito que sua dúvida inicial já foi sanada, entretanto conforme você vai desenvolvendo você acaba evoluindo seu projeto e encontrando novas dúvidas. Aconselho você a marcar essa [resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/3117) e se necessário iniciar outro tópico com a sua nova dúvida. Entretanto, dê uma olhada nesse tópico antes para ver se não lhe ajuda um pouco: [Posicionamento de componentes usando GridBagLayout](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/14099/3117)

Comment: Obrigado a vocês!